# Contact Form Error

Tags: html, asp.net, forms, contact-form

I have a website which has a contact form:

```
index.html

<form id="form" action="contact.aspx" method="POST">
<p><label>Your Name</label><input name="nome" type="text"></p>
<p><label>Your Email</label><input name="email" type="text"></p>
<p><label>Your Message</label><textarea name="mensagem"></textarea></p>
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This forms requests a asp.net page (contact.aspx)

```
<%@ page language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>

<%
MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
objEmail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@mydomain.com");
objEmail.To.Add("myemail@mydomain.com");
objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
objEmail.Subject = "Mysubject";
objEmail.Body = "Mycontent";
SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient();
objSmtp.Host = "localhost";
objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@mydomain.com", "mypassword");
objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
%>
```

When someone uses the contact form, I can receive the email. However, on the subject, it only appears "Mysubject" and, on the body, it only appears "Mycontent".
What do I have to change in order to receive the data that the user put on the form?

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the posted data in Request.Form by their name. Your code should look like this:

```
<%@ page language="C#" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net.Mail" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Net" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Text" %>

<%
MailMessage objEmail = new MailMessage();
objEmail.From = new MailAddress("myemail@mydomain.com");
objEmail.To.Add("myemail@mydomain.com");
objEmail.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
objEmail.IsBodyHtml = true;
objEmail.Subject = Request.Form["subject"];
objEmail.Body = Request.Form["mensagem"];
SmtpClient objSmtp = new SmtpClient();
objSmtp.Host = "localhost";
objSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myemail@mydomain.com", "mypassword");
objSmtp.Send(objEmail);
%>
```

In the html you are missing the "subject" field.  Your markup should be like this:

```
<form id="form" action="contact.aspx" method="POST">
<p><label>Your Name</label><input name="nome" type="text"></p>
<p><label>Your Email</label><input name="email" type="text"></p>
<p><label>Your Subject</label><input name="subject" type="text"></p>
<p><label>Your Message</label><textarea name="mensagem"></textarea></p>
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like he's also not capturing the user's name or email, I'd prepend it to the body, for extra credit :)